# Crossover for generating fixed number of points distribution with a genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, implementation, genetic-algorithm

I have an optimization problem in hand, which requires generating a constant number of points (x,y) in a fixed square [a1, a2] x [b1,b2].

There is a constraint of maintaining a minimum distance between any 2 points. I am trying to implement a genetic algorithm for this problem, what will be good crossover and mutation operation for the genetic algorithm in this search space ?

Currently, I think for mutation we can have random perturbations for each point in both x and y coordinates with normal distribution.
But I don't have any ideas for a crossover operator.

Answer (score 0):

During the crossover check the minimum distance constraint `m` to satisfy it. For example, when a pair `(x1, y1)` is selected for crossover, you can limit the other pair `(x2, y2)` by applying `y2^2 > c^2 - x1^2` and `x2^2 > c^2 - y1^2`.

Comment: Croosover requires selecting two individuals and creating a new individual from them, here one individual will be one configuration of points in the grid. I don't quite understand how you are proposing to do crossover ?

Comment: @VaibhavThakkar Right. The other pair should be taken from existed pairs that satisfy the mentioned constraints.